# I use QPrinter for printing operations. How do I know whether the printing is successful?

Tags: c++, qt

I use QPrinter for multi-page printing, I want to get the result of the print success or failure, and then different pop-ups pop up depending on the returned result. I wonder how to get this print result?

```cpp
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
QPainter painter(&printer);
for (int i = 0; i < pathList.size(); i++)
{
    QString path = pathList[i];
    QImage image(path);
    QRect rect = painter.viewport();
    size.scale(rect.size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    painter.setViewport(rect.x() + (rect.width() - image.width()) / 2, rect.y() + (rect.height() - image.height()) / 2, image.width(), image.height());
    painter.setWindow(image.rect());
    painter.drawImage(0, 0, image);
    if (i < (pathList.size() - 1))
        printer.newPage();
}
painter.end();
```

I tried using the Windows Api, but didn't find one available

Comment: Check the return value of `painter.end()`?

Comment: It didn't work after I tried